# Question involving probability

Tags: probability

Think of a card game. cards can either be "big" or other cards

we consider a game with 2 players

each player has a deck of 40 cards

each player shuffles their deck, deals 7 cards which is their hand

assume that player 1 has 10 big cards in their deck and player 2 has 20

I would appreciate if you could answer the simpler question first, and post your answer immediately after figuring it out.

Simpler question: What is the probability that player 2 has exactly 3 big cards in their hand?

Tricker question: What is the probability that player 2 has more big cards in their hand than player one?

After working for 3 hours on the trickier question, I got the answer wrong. I do not know whether my answer to the easier question is correct, however I think my issue may come from getting the easier question wrong.

Here's my approach for the easier problem:

Imagine that player two pulls out 4 "non-big" cards in a row, then pulls out 3 "big cards."

The probability of this occurring is ((20/40)(19/39)(18/38)(17/37)(20/36)(19/35)(18/34)).

If player two has exactly 3 big cards in their hand, there are 35 ways that all those 7 cards can be arranged (7 choose 3), all of which are equally likely.

Multiplying 35 by the long product computed before, I get the answer of 0.296, or 29.6%.

Is that correct? If not, where did I go wrong?

Comment: The calculation is correct, and so is the answer.  I find it easier to think of this way.  There are $\binom{20}{3}$ ways to choose $3$ big cards, $\binom{20}4$ ways to choose $4$ small cards, and $\binom{40}7$ ways to choose $7$ cards, so the answer is $$\frac{\binom{20}3\binom{20}4}{\binom{40}3}$$ which is the same as what you got.

Comment: Hello Saulspatz. Thank you for answering. Could you please take a swing at the "trickier" question? It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $$\frac{\pmatrix{20\\3} \pmatrix{20\\4}}{\pmatrix{40\\7}}.$$ Please see. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4144874/problem-involving-probabilities/4144895#4144895

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the second problem is particularly tricky, but it's long.  All we can hope to do is to arrange the calculations efficiently.

The probability that play $1$ has exactly $k$ big cards, where $k=0,1,2,\cdots,6$ is $$p_k:=\frac{\binom{10}{k}\binom{30}{7-k}}{\binom{40}7}$$  Now we need to know the probability $q_{k+1}$ that player $2$ has at least $k+1$ big cards.  When $k=0$ we need $q_1$, the probability that he has at least $1$ big card.  This is the complement of the probability that he has no big cards:$$q_1=1-\frac{\binom{30}{7}}{\binom{40}{7}}$$

Once we have computed $q_k$, it's easy to computed $q_{k+1}$.  The probability that player $2$ has at least $k+1$ big cards is the probability that he has at least $k$ big cards, minus the probability that he has exactly $k$ big cards: $$q_{k+1}=q_k-\frac{\binom{10}{k}\binom{30}{7-k}}{\binom{40}7}$$

Once we've computed all these probabilities, the probability that player $2$ has more big cards than player $1$ is $$\sum_{k=0}^6p_kq_{k+1}$$